# Passing method with list of base type in return type as a parameter causes wrong method signature error

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I'm trying to create generic method to filter results from  several method returning lists of types that are deriving from same base type. I prepared a simplified version of my problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Animal 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Cat : Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetFilteredAnimals("Pe", GetCats));
    }

    private static List<Cat> GetCats()
    {   
        return new List<Cat>() { new Cat { Name = "Sphinx" }, new Cat { Name = "Persian" } };
    }

    private static List<Dog> GetDogs()
    {
        return new List<Dog>() { new Dog { Name = "Bulldog"}, new Dog { Name = "Dalmatian" } };
    }

    private static List<Animal> GetFilteredAnimals(string f, Func<List<Animal>> method)
    {
        var animals = method();

         return animals.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith(f)).ToList<Animal>();
    }
}
```

The method

```
GetFilteredAnimals("Pe", GetCats)
```

does not work because `GetCats` does not return list of `Animal`. Is it possible to do such generic method for lists? As far as I know, if I used single objects instead of lists it would work.

The working code for this is [here on .NET Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/2hXbeg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using C# 4+ and .NET 4+, you can get this to work using [generic covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private static List<Animal> GetFilteredAnimals(string f, Func<IEnumerable<Animal>> method)
```

A `List<Cat>` can't be treated as a `List<Animal>` - but it *can* be treated as an `IEnumerable<Animal>` because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T`.

Likewise `Func<T>` is covariant in `T`, so a `Func<List<Cat>>` can be treated as a `Func<IEnumerable<Animal>>`... so it then compiles.

Comment: Thanks! It now works. The funny part is that before asking the question I checked the very page you linked but I misunderstood the table on the bottom. I checked that `Func<TResult>` was there so it should be fine. I need to read more on covariance/contravariance for sure.